# Find $\int\sin^3(2x+1)dx$.

Tags: indefinite-integrals

> Find $\int\sin^3(2x+1)dx$. Having three different results which one is right right?

1.$y= -\frac{\cos (2x+1)}{2} +\frac{1}{24\cos(6x^3)}  -\frac{1}{4\cos(2x+1)}+c$

2. $y=-\cos (2x+1) + \cos^3(2x+1) +c.$
3. $y= -\frac{\cos(6x+3)}{24}   -\frac{3}{8}\cos(2x+1) +c$

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting. You can simply evaluate the integral with [WolframAlpha](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to find out the correct result so if you want us to show you where your mistake is, you have to post what you have done to solve the problem.

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: This is very hard to read.  Keep in mind that two solutions which differ by a constant are equally valid. Here is the [Wolfram alpha solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%5E3(2x%2B1)) for comparison.

Comment: What have you tried in order to check if a result is correct? Did you differentiate them? Where did these results come from?

Comment: I have integrated by three different ways . In first I used the formula of sin3x . In second I substitute  (2x+1) = u.         So I want to know that three of them are right  or not.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$${\displaystyle \sin ^{3}x={\frac {3\sin x -\sin(3x )}{4}}}$$
and 
$${\displaystyle \cos ^{3}\theta ={\frac {3\cos \theta +\cos(3\theta )}{4}}}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

1. Substitute $u = 2x + 1$. What will $du$ be?
2. Use the [reduction formula](http://www.vias.org/calculus/07_trigonometric_functions_05_03.html).